# How can I join the big chasis with SATA drives to computer

Tags: motherboard, sata, nas, chassis

I am planning to order [this chasis](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/4U-Rackmount-20xSATA-SAS-HotSwap-HDD-Tray-Backplane-MiniSAS-eATX-Chassis-NEW-/351047293061?pt=US_Rackmount_Cases_Chassis&hash=item51bc0c9885) with 20 SATA Drives

It has only chasis and powersupply.

How am I supposed to use this.

As I have understood I need to add motherboard to the chasis and make it as NAS.

But my main question is how do I connect 20 SATA drives to motherboard.

DO I need motherboard with 20 SATA connections

Comment: For future reference i should be I when referring to oneself!

Comment: If you have no idea how to use it, why are you considering buying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a rack mount case for a server. You need to put a server motherboard in it. The normal approach would be to have a RAID capable controller card that attaches to the mobo, this will have all the connectors on it.

The last but one picture in the details shows such a controller board in place, recognised by the many red connectors.